# After adding ML Kit for Translate api on Android, Its increasing app size dramatically

Tags: android, google-mlkit

After adding mlkit translation api `implementation 'com.google.mlkit:translate:17.0.0'` my app size increase dramatically.

My primary app size was 12mb in release build after added mlkit it's now 35mb. How to decrease my app size?

Comment: Well, [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/language/translation/android) states that _"Language models are around 30MB, so don't download them unnecessarily, and only download them using Wi-Fi unless the user has specified otherwise. You should also delete unneeded models"_.

Comment: Thanks for response. My app size has increased Without download any models. I have just added  ```implementation 'com.google.mlkit:translate:17.0.0'``` dependency on my project and app size has increased dramatically.

Comment: You can try to exclude unused architectures and other options mentioned here https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/tips/reduce-app-size

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, and adding that functionality to my app increased my app size about 50%, although based on official google documentation, it wasn't supposed to be contributing to app size, because google ml kit language translation api supported installation path is categorized in dynamically downloaded and it doesn't have to be contributing to the app size; but it looks like that this app size increase is due to the base library size and not individual per language models.

However there are multiple ways to reduce app size such as :

- Building your app as android app bundle, by that google play or any other store that support app bundles can provide users version of your application that matches their device specification (e.g. their specific CPU architecture)
- Move optional ML features to dynamic feature modules so that google play can allow certain features of your app to be delivered conditionally or downloaded on demand.
- Exclude unused ML Kit binaries

The first solution (building as app bundle) can reduce your app size significantly, because we currently have 4 major CPU architectures and google ml kit translation library uses about 6 MB per architecture, so you trough google play store can provide users version of your app that matches their device architecture and this reduces the extra space that is used by library about 3/4 !, i will post a screenshot for different elements that contributed to my app size below (note how much space is used for translation library per architecture):

[Android studio APK analyzer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0672t.png)

It worth noted that solutions above mostly requires your app to be release through google play store (or any other store that support this functionality).

Further document links:

https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/tips/installation-paths
https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/tips/reduce-app-size

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I solved this issue by shifting the feature into Dynamic Delivery.