# How to decrease the size of ml kit on device translate library without Excluding unused ML Kit binaries?

Tags: android, size, reduce, google-mlkit

When I added the dependency 'implementation com.google.mlkit:translate:17.0.1', my APK size increased from 2 MB to 58.5 MB, and this is before downloading any model. While Googling to find a solution, I came across this article 'https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/tips/reduce-app-size'. However, the problem with this is that it is based on architectures and guides you to remove 64-bit binary files, which is not what I want.

What i want ?
I want to use only those classes of ml kit library which is used by my project only. I dont need any other classes which comes with the ml kit package/library.

For Example:-

```
import com.google.mlkit.common.model.DownloadConditions
import com.google.mlkit.nl.translate.TranslateLanguage
import com.google.mlkit.nl.translate.Translation
import com.google.mlkit.nl.translate.Translator
import com.google.mlkit.nl.translate.TranslatorOptions
```

These are 5 classes I want, or any referenced class which is used by these class.
And I know ML Kit for Android is a closed-source library. But if anyone know how to reduce the size by this method or any other please let me know.

Links I have read:-

[After adding ML Kit for Translate api on Android, Its increasing app size dramatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72258003/after-adding-ml-kit-for-translate-api-on-android-its-increasing-app-size-dramat)

[How to reduce Size of app while using Mlkit translation library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75932760/how-to-reduce-size-of-app-while-using-mlkit-translation-library)

https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis

https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/tips/reduce-app-size